# DCount returning 0 but should return 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following `DCount` code in my VBA:

```
If DCount("*", "tbl2Employee_Order", _
    "[Operation_Date] = #" & Operation_Date & _
    "# AND [Employee_ID]= " & Employee_ID & _
    " AND [Order_ID] = " & Order_ID & _
    " AND [Model_Operation_ID] = " & MO_ID) = 0 Then

    'some code to insert into tbl2Employee_Order
Else
    'some code to update the existing record
End If
```

However, my `DCount` always returns 0, even if the record already exists. The following:

```
Debug.Print Operation_Date, Employee_ID, Order_ID, MO_ID, DCount("*", "tbl2Employee_Order", "[Operation_Date] = #" & Operation_Date & "# AND [Employee_ID]= " & Employee_ID & " AND [Order_ID] = " & Order_ID & " AND [Model_Operation_ID] = " & MO_ID)
```

Returns the expected values such as:

```
08/05/2015     2             526           1107          0
```

Apart from the last one, which is expected to be 1 (record already exists).

tbl2EmployeeOrder has this record:

```
Operation_Date: 08/05/2015
Employee_ID: 2
Order_ID: 526
Model_Operation_ID = 1107
```

Interestingly enough, it used to work without problem a few weeks ago, suddenly it behaves as if the record doesn't already exist.

Edit:

The following:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Operation_Date), TypeName(Employee_ID), TypeName(Order_ID), TypeName(MO_ID)
```

Results in:

```
Date          Integer       Integer       Integer
```

And those are also the variable types in the tbl2Employee_Order.

Similarly, if I use `DLookup` (with some column name) instead of `DCount` I get a `Null` value returned.

Comment: Is your date *variable* (not the field) May 8 or August 5? Access SQL needs the date in mm/dd/yyyy format - unless that has been changed recently. Cross-checked it in Acc. query editor?

Comment: I have narrows down the problem to being the date (ie. if date is removed from `DCount`, it finds the record). However, I tried returning the date and it returns it from the table in the same format as I search it by (ie. Dlookup("Operation_Date"....) returns 08/05/2015 and if I then evaluate (debug.print mydate = Dlookup(...)) it returns true. Any idea? :x

Answer (score 2):

did you change regional settings ?  how about

```
If DCount("*", "tbl2Employee_Order", _
"[Operation_Date] = #" & Format(Operation_Date,"mm/dd/yyyy") & _
"# AND [Employee_ID]= " & Employee_ID & _
" AND [Order_ID] = " & Order_ID & _
" AND [Model_Operation_ID] = " & MO_ID) = 0 Then
```

remove the date criteria to see if it works

Comment: Indeed this is the solution, I have found it after @LocEngineer pointed me in this direction (with format) and found it was the root of the problem.

Comment: Couldn't find a VBA analogy to DateTime.Parse() - nice to learn that Format() does the trick. Thanks for pointing that out.